# Actionscript - Update slider position dynamically

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a slider control that I need to update based on the time of the song.  How do I move the slider cursor over dynamically?

I tried this and it didn't update:

```
sldAudioPosition.value = channel.position;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which AS version are you using.

With your slider you need to set a maximum value as well. Without a maximum value there's no way that the slider knows where it should be.
Set your maximum value to the song length, then the code your using at the moment should work.

Depending on the AS version you may have to update the stage afterwards as well.

Comment: I'm using AS 3.  Right now the slider max is determined dynamically by the sound length.  I just need the pointer to update with each second that passes.

Comment: For this you need to add an "enter frame" event listener. Every time that the enter frame function you've defined is called then run your script `sldAudioPosition.value = channel.position;` and this should get it updating for you.